# Ble not connect in android 5.0 or more

Tags: android

When I connect my ble device to android phone in kitkat than it's working fine. But in case of lollipop or android 5.0 scanning work's properly and also device get connected. But after 5-10 seconds it's get automatically disconnected. Why this is happening i don't understand. Please help me and reply me as soon as possible. My code is,

```
bluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
        ScanCallback mScanCallback=new ScanCallback() {
            @Override
             public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
              Log.i("callbackType", String.valueOf(callbackType));
              Log.i("result", result.toString());
              BluetoothDevice btDevice = result.getDevice();
              addDevice(btDevice);

             }
        };
```

connect code is like that

```
public boolean connect(BluetoothDevice device) {

    // if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
    // Log.w(TAG,
    // "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
    // System.out.println("devices mBluetoothAdapter && address null ");
    // return false;
    // }
    //
    // final BluetoothDevice device =
    // mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

    if (device == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
        // System.out.println("devices  devices null ");
        return false;
    }
    // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the
    // autoConnect
    // parameter to false.
    mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
    Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
    // System.out.println("devices Trying to create a new connection.");
    mBluetoothDeviceAddress = device.getName();
    mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;

    try {
        Thread.sleep(20);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
}
```